# google homepage will not load in an iframe

Tags: iframe

Really cannot understand why yahoo iframe works but the google one does not:

```
<!DOCTYPE html><html><body>
<iframe frameborder="0" src="http://www.yahoo.com"></iframe>
<iframe frameborder="0" src="http://www.google.com"></iframe>
</body></html>
```

any ideas?

Answer (score 29):

From http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc288472(v=vs.85).aspx#search

**Clickjacking Defense:** Some hackers try to trick users into clicking buttons that appear to perform safe or harmless functions, but instead perform unrelated tasks. Clickjackers embed malicious code or "redress" the user interface by using transparent frames that overlay specific UI elements with misleading text and images. To help prevent clickjacking, Web site owners can send an HTTP response header named X-Frame-Options with HTML pages to restrict how the page may be framed.

```
X-Frame-Options: Deny
```

If the X-Frame-Options value contains the token Deny, Internet Explorer 8 prevents the page from rendering if it is contained within a frame. If the value contains the token SameOrigin, Internet Explorer will not render the page if the top level-browsing-context differs from the origin of the page containing the directive. Blocked pages are replaced with a "This content cannot be displayed in a frame" error page.

Comment: @Pacerier I don't believe so: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy#Origin_determination_rules

Answer (score 1):

Using IE8, I get the following message in the Google iframe

> This content cannot be displayed in a frame
>
> To help protect the security of information you enter into this website, the publisher of this content does not allow it to be displayed in a frame.

Looks like Google uses some code to prevent it's content from being displayed in an iframe

EDIT:

I found a decent explanation here: [http://forums.asp.net/p/1733782/4654025.aspx/1?I+am+gettignthe+following+error+in+asp+net+with+facebook+app+early+it+is+working+fine+Once+i+click+on+Open+this+content+in+a+new+window+](http://forums.asp.net/p/1733782/4654025.aspx/1?I%20am%20gettignthe%20following%20error%20in%20asp%20net%20with%20facebook%20app%20early%20it%20is%20working%20fine%20Once%20i%20click%20on%20Open%20this%20content%20in%20a%20new%20window%20)

Answer (score 1):

You can show google in iframe using the below link by passing igu=1

```
https://www.google.com/webhp?igu=1
```

HTML Code:

```
<html>
<body>
<iframe src="https://www.google.com/webhp?igu=1" height="750" width="850"></iframe>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

I have also same error. 
I just included  inside  tag and its works for me fine.
i tested it in chrome, firefox and opera

```
<div style="height:820px; width:100%" >
 <div  style="background-color:Green; height:50px; width:100%"> </div>
 <iframe id="content"   style="height:820px; width:100%; overflow:auto;" src="http://www.google.com" ></iframe>
 </div>
```

Comment: This is not working for me. Could you please explain?

Comment: Not working....