# Getting youtube.com to load in iFrame

Tags: html, iframe, youtube, embed

Can't get Youtube's homepage, or any other youtube.com prefixed URL to load in an iFrame. Any suggestions or insights?

**Code:**

```
<iframe src="http://youtube.com" frameborder="0" width="1020" height="560"
 horizontalscrolling="no" verticalscrolling="yes"></iframe>
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Youtube does not allow embedding. Only http://www.youtube.com/embed/* is allowed, which is for HTML5 videos.

Comment: I had a feeling that was the case. Thanks for confirming.

Comment: @staticwave don't forget to click the check mark next to your favorite answer.

Answer (score 4):

youtube.com cannot be loaded in an iframe.

A possible duplicate: [See this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8524449/google-homepage-will-not-load-in-an-iframe)