# Setting an iframe in a modal does not work on mobile phone

Tags: jquery, html

Am setting am iframe in a modal of specific links when clicked.It works fine on the computer but when i use mobile phone browser the modal pops up but doesn't show the iframe 
This what i have done please tell me where the error is

sample link code

```
<a href="http://www.youtube.com/v/qyoXH32WXvg&amp;autoplay=1" class="link" >
```

Then the jquery code is here

```
<script>
$('.link').on('click',function (event) {
    var src = $(this).attr("href");
    $('#myModal').modal('show');
    $('#myModal iframe').attr('src', src);
    event.preventDefault();
});

$('#myModal button').click(function () {
    $('#myModal iframe').removeAttr('src');
});
```

Where am i going wrong

Comment: can you give us a jsfiddle example?

Comment: What device is the phone? Will it play flash video content?

Comment: Have a look at this, it could be related: http://stackoverflow.com/a/8698777/1238244

Comment: @Stefan let me create a fiddle then i will post it.You can have a look at this part of the actual site http://deveint.com/solar click patners menu the you can see logos click on sample e.g aljazeera

Comment: @Iharby i have tested using a windows phone 8.1 and an iphone. Yes it will play video content as i have done it in the code