# iframe source not found

Tags: php, html, mysql, iframe

I am trying to use iFrame to dispaly some random videos. The links are stored in a database so i am using a loop to get them and use them as source for iFrame. When i just print out the url's it works fine they all appear, but when I try to add them as src for iFrame it wont appear. I get an empty box.

```
$loop = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM video") or die (mysql_error());
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($loop)) {
    $tmp = $row['videos'];
    //echo $tmp;
?>
    <iframe width="420" height="315" src="<?php echo $tmp; ?>" ></iframe>
<?php   
}
?>
```

Comment: what is the url format?

Comment: Please give us the contents of `$tmp`. I would like to see that if there's anything there that might cause the problem.

Comment: where is your iframe files are stored, and show the ` $tmp ` variable data

Comment: $tmp is just a variable that I use to store the link in. It could look like the following as well. (With link I mean just a youtube, for example https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Y0hKpdnuXnw)
<iframe width="420" height="315" src="<?php echo $row['videos']; ?>" ></iframe>

When i echo out $row['videos'] (or $tmp) i get all my links displayed

Comment: @Manam what is the value of $tmp?

Comment: That can never work. You need to start your `src` with http://.

Comment: when I paste the link on here the http disappears :S

Answer (score -1):

Make sure `$tmp` starts with http://.

```
$loop = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM video") or die (mysql_error());
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($loop)) {
    $tmp = $row['videos'];
    $tmp = strpos($tmp, "http://") ? $tmp : "http://" . $tmp;
    //echo $tmp;
?>
    <iframe width="420" height="315" src="<?php echo $tmp; ?>" ></iframe>
<?php   
}
?>
```

Comment: My bad, the links are already starting with html: https: //www.youtube.com/watch?v=Y0hKpdnuXnw
But it does not work either way

Comment: As mentioned in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8698742/getting-youtube-com-to-load-in-iframe YouTube cannot be embedded other than links that starts with http://www.youtube.com/embed/

I actually had no idea about that before I posted my answer.

Comment: Ohh now I see. It actually works when I use an embedded link :D