# Why is my video not being displayed?

Tags: html, css, web

My code:

```
<iframe height="420" width="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ddR9g- 
YzE8g" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

Problem is, video is not being displayed as shown in the codepen

The codepen: https://codepen.io/don0ts/pen/gjYJvq

Answer (score 3, accepted):

He you should use "/embed" along with the youtube link. A correct way of doing this should be :

```html
<iframe width="420" height="315"
src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/tgbNymZ7vqY?autoplay=1">
</iframe>
```

Comment: Don't forget to mark it correct then :) @GustavoJRiosOrdoñez

Answer (score 0):

Check the dev tools (usually with F12) 
It shows this:

Refused to display 'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ddR9g-YzE8g' in a frame because it set 'X-Frame-Options' to 'sameorigin'.

See: [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8698742/getting-youtube-com-to-load-in-iframe)

```
<iframe width="560" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/ddR9g-YzE8g" frameborder="0" allow="autoplay; encrypted-media" allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should actually write this:

```
<iframe frameborder="0" height="190" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/ddR9gYzE8g" width="100%"></iframe>
```