# iframe embedded YouTube video unavailable on NodeJS

Tags: node.js, iframe, youtube, ip, localhost

I was trying to implement a simple player with a web server on a VM when I stumbled across this issue.

server.js

```
const express = require('express'); 
var app = express();
var path = __dirname + '/views/' ;
app.get("/",function(req,res,next){
  res.sendFile(path + "index.html");
});
app.listen(1823);
console.log('listening');
```

index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Alpha</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <iframe id="player" width="640" height="360" src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/N0dbGGvsjf8?enablejsapi=1&origin=http://192.168.150.129">
    </iframe>
  </body>
</html>
```

Accessing the site locally with http://localhost:1823 works just fine.
However, accessing the site from the local network such as http://192.168.150.129:1823 the iframe(?) stops working.

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/w5Sbg.png)

Same video works on [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/6958fnsm/).

NB: This only happens on *certain* videos.

e.g. with this iframe

```
<iframe id="player" type="text/html" width="640" height="360" src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/PfYnvDL0Qcw?enablejsapi=1&origin=http://192.168.150.129">
</iframe>
```

Both localhost and IP work the same.

All seems to point towards Node doing something?
Why some videos *work* and others do not?

Comment: YouTube is detecting that it is being loaded in an iframe and it's blocking the content. And localhost may get different treatment than a normal IP. Here's another similar question you might have a look at: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8698742/getting-youtube-com-to-load-in-iframe  Good luck!

Comment: Nice suggestion but that's not the case. Unfortunately this issue happens only with 'popular' videos, such as "Hey Jude" or "Bohemian Rhapsody" etc.

I also thought about the Firewall, I tried allowing anything from anything to anything and yet the issue was still there.

Comment: I faced the same problem. @Joshelin do you have something to find out? Looks like it is about **origin** and **cookies**...

Comment: I'm sorry but no. Would be nice to find an answer after turning in my project and actually getting full marks with this bug still present.