# Why iframe is not loading all webpages in winjs app?

Tags: iframe, winjs

Hi All,

I took a blank WinJS Store app and placed the below code in default.html file

`<iframe src="http://www.google.com" height="400" width="400"></iframe>`

But the iframe is not loading the google home page. The page is left blank. While if I replace the src value to "http://www.palermo4.com" its working fine. Why is this strange behavior. Do we need to acquire any other permissions kind of thing for some urls? Kindly help me out.

Thanks in Advance

Comment: possible duplicate of [google homepage will not load in an iframe](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8524449/google-homepage-will-not-load-in-an-iframe)

Comment: palermo4 is a magical site with special properties only fairies can see :)

Answer (score 0):

```
You can't load ooogle in iframe,since they are blocking this facility.
You can use Iframe for some other sites,but you won't get full controll of their JS[Loading sites] ,may have to face some breaking point in such sites.
```

if you really want to load google try this,.

```
1. Make your default browser as IE10.
2. trigger an event.

function openYourLink(){    
var url = new Windows.Foundation.Uri("http://www.google.com")
Windows.System.Launcher.launchUriAsync(url);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In Windows 8.1 you'll also be able to use the webview control  which is not sensitive to frame-busting code that sites like Google use.