# HTML iframe not loading the scr path

Tags: html

This is the code I am using. There is an `iframe` on a table I made.

```
<td height="100%">
<iframe src="http://mk7vrlist.altervista.org/combocalculator/indextts.html" width="100%" height="100%">
  Your browser doesn't load this iframe.
</iframe>
</td>
```

By the way, inside my iframe I don't see anything and the url I put is not showed. I've googled around this but I don't find a solution. Any help?

Comment: Works for me. http://jsfiddle.net/Y6pVy/

Comment: So I think I have problems with my browser, I am using the latest version of Firefox

Comment: Well have you tried other browsers? Also, be careful for security settings.

Comment: @AlbertoRossi Did you change the iframe from google.it to something else? I think it was initially google.it for the first time i read your question :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sites like google and yahoo prevent their pages from getting loaded in an iframe

Check this stackoverflow thread [google homepage will not load in an iframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8524449/google-homepage-will-not-load-in-an-iframe)

They are using `X-Frame-Options: Deny` to block their content from loading in an iframe.

Try anything else other than google and yahoo and you will see that it works

```
<td height="100%">
<iframe src="http://www.w3schools.com" width="100%" height="100%">
  Your browser doesn't load this iframe.
</iframe>
</td>
```

Comment: Thank you, and using that 'width="100%" height="100%"' It will adjust the height of the iframe with all the content of my page, right?

Comment: The site he linked does not use X-Frame-Options. And by the way, w3schools is a horrible site. Even to test stuff I wouldn't want to use it. Unless that tests eventually resulted in the site being closed for good of course :D

Comment: @AlbertoRossi Use pixels instead of percent ..somthing like 500px for both width and height. you'll get more control on how your iframe should look like

Comment: @ThiefMaster the first time i read his qstn the iframe source was google.it , alberto might have updated it laters trying a different possibility

Comment: @Raghu Yes I changed the link. By the way I still cannot see any link on my iframe. Should I change some settings on my browser? (gonna accept the question)

Comment: @AlbertoRossi It should work, can you try loading this jsfiddle on your local ?http://jsfiddle.net/aTUZJ/ let me know

Comment: Yeah can load that, I see my webpage in the iframe @jsfiddle

Comment: @AlbertoRossi BTW , Which browser are you running on ?

Comment: @AlbertoRossi Cool, also note that im using pixels instead of percent for width and height :)

Comment: Firefox 23.0.1 . Now I am downloading Chrome, I wanna see if I can see that damn iframe

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/36365/discussion-between-raghu-and-alberto-rossi)