# How to change iframe src by clicking a with jquery?

Tags: jquery, html, iframe

My js file looks like this:

```
$('.button').live("click",function () { 
      $('.tresc').attr("src", "http://www.google.com/");
});
```

and html:

```
<a href="javascript:void(0)" class="button">Odnośnik 01</a>
```

I want to change iframe with class *tresc* src to for ex. "http://google.com", by clicking a with class *button* using jquery. My solution doesn't work anyway.
Any advices?

Comment: Depending on your jQuery version.. `$.fn.live == 'undefined'`

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2930315/changing-iframe-source-with-jquery

Comment: What is your actual problem?? Detecting click on a link or changing the source of iframe. Give a alert inside click function to see if click is working correctly. If possible make a jsFiddle.

Answer (score 0):

There are a few issues.  First, if the jQuery version is > 1.6 the code should use `on` to attach the event.  It would also be a good idea to prevent the default event so that the code does not attempt to navigate to another page.  Also, I would recommend switching to `prop` instead of `attr`.

This leaves us with:

```
$('.button').on("click",function (e) { 
      e.preventDefault();
      $('.tresc').prop("src", "http://www.google.com/");
});
```

However, this still will not work because the Google security settings prevent the page from being loaded within an `iframe`.  See an explanation why [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8524449/google-homepage-will-not-load-in-an-iframe).