# angular4 iframe doesn't display the src link page

Tags: angular, iframe

> Template:

```
<iframe  width="100%" height="100%"  [src]="url"></iframe>
```

> Component :

I have already transform the url to a  safeUrl:

```
ngOnInit() {
  this.url = this.sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustResourceUrl('https://www.google.com/');
}
```

---

But the page still doesn't show anything，refer to inspect:
[empty content of the src link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/256Bi.png)

Does anybody know why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is 100% fine

> The issue is with `https://www.google.com/`, this url

**For more detail, please read :**

[google homepage will not load in an iframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8524449/google-homepage-will-not-load-in-an-iframe)

[How to show google.com in an iframe?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8700636/how-to-show-google-com-in-an-iframe)

---

Here is the working example of it :

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-iframe

Comment: Google  sets 'X-Frame-Options' to 'sameorigin'. Is there any web that doesn't set this option? I just want to try the iframe function.

Comment: @DanteJiang, try this one , https://www.youtube.com/embed/cChkPnpN15c , also used in exmaple

Comment: @DanteJiang, will you please also upvote the answer?